# Deserialize a GSON generated JSON string n C#

Tags: c#, json, gson

I have a JSON generated through java using GSON. I want to recreate the same fields in C#. The JSON looks something like this.

```
{
    "bool1": true,
    "long1": 0,
    "double1": 500.0,
    "int1": 1,
    "double2": 0.4,
    "double3": 0.3,
    "double4": 1.0,
    "double5": 0.1,
    "int2": 0,
    "int3": 0,
    "long2": 20160901,
    "class1object1": {
        "serialVersionUID": 1,
        "class1int1": 0,
        "class1int2": 0,
        "class1int3": 0,
        "class1double1": 68.3,
        "class1doubleArray1": [68.3],
        "class1double2": 65.45,
        "class1doubleArray2": [65.45],
        "class1int4": 1
    },
    "class1object2": {
        "serialVersionUID": 1,
        "class1int1": 135,
        "class1int2": 138,
        "class1int3": 105,
        "class1double1": 68.1,
        "class1doubleArray1": [67.57, 67.6, 67.48, 67.45, 67.39, 67.42, 67.38, 67.37, 67.35, 67.35, 67.37, 67.35, 67.36, 67.37, 67.35, 67.37, 67.38],
        "class1double2": 67.26,
        "class1doubleArray2": [67.5, 67.53, 67.46, 67.4, 67.39, 67.38, 67.37, 67.32, 67.33, 67.33, 67.33, 67.35, 67.36, 67.33, 67.33, 67.37, 67.34],
        "class1int4": 240
    },
    "int4": 1,
    "class2object1": {
        "serialVersionUID": 1,
        "class2double1": 2.8499999999999943,
        "class2double2": 1.6758422688703467,
        "class2double3": 0.09523809523809523
    },
}
```

The definitions for all these classes and other fields are already there in my C# application. Also if required, the names of fields can be kept the same as they are in the JSON.

Can someone please help me with what tool should I use in order to achieve this and how? Also there is a possibility of NaN/Inf values as well (Secondary problem, not very important and can be omitted from JSON if required.

Comment: Please use this link: http://json2csharp.com/

Comment: You can use [Json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/) to auto-generate your clasess, and [JsonNET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) to deserialize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [JSON2CSHARP](http://json2csharp.com/) or copy json to clipboard > go to Visual Studio > Edit>Paste Special>Paste JSON as Classes. It's give you model classes. Uisng `Newtonsoft.Json` package you can deserialize your json:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootClassName>("json");
```

Your model class should look:

```
 public class Class1
{
    public int serialVersionUID { get; set; }
    public int class1int1 { get; set; }
    public int class1int2 { get; set; }
    public int class1int3 { get; set; }
    public double class1double1 { get; set; }
    public List<double> class1doubleArray1 { get; set; }
    public double class1double2 { get; set; }
    public List<double> class1doubleArray2 { get; set; }
    public int class1int4 { get; set; }
}

public class Class2
{
    public int serialVersionUID { get; set; }
    public int class1int1 { get; set; }
    public int class1int2 { get; set; }
    public int class1int3 { get; set; }
    public double class1double1 { get; set; }
    public List<double> class1doubleArray1 { get; set; }
    public double class1double2 { get; set; }
    public List<double> class1doubleArray2 { get; set; }
    public int class1int4 { get; set; }
}

public class Class3
{
    public int serialVersionUID { get; set; }
    public double class2double1 { get; set; }
    public double class2double2 { get; set; }
    public double class2double3 { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public bool bool1 { get; set; }
    public int long1 { get; set; }
    public double double1 { get; set; }
    public int int1 { get; set; }
    public double double2 { get; set; }
    public double double3 { get; set; }
    public double double4 { get; set; }
    public double double5 { get; set; }
    public int int2 { get; set; }
    public int int3 { get; set; }
    public int long2 { get; set; }
    public Class1 Class1 { get; set; }
    public Class2 Class2 { get; set; }
    public int int4 { get; set; }
    public Class3 Class3 { get; set; }
}
```

Also if you want use others  name in C# classes you need use `JsonProperty(PropertyName = "yourJsonName")`,this allows you to specify a different name this example should help:

```
public class Foo
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "fooJSONname")]
    public int FooNumber { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Is there a way where I can specify which datatype I want to use while creating the JSON through GSON?

Comment: I do not know that's what you mean   `[JsonConverter(typeof(datatype))]`